# Cannot resolve symbol norm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, breeze

The following is a code snippet that I'm working on with for a recommender. Although,

```
import breeze.linalg.Vector
```

been made, the error mentioned above appeared when calling 'norm'. Can someone please suggest a fix for this matter and the reason. The code snippet is as follows.

```
object CosineDistance extends DistanceMetric with Serializable {
  def getDistance(v1: Vector[Double], v2: Vector[Double]) = {

    val dotProduct: Double = v1 dot v2
    val v1norm: Double = v1.norm(2.0)
    val v2norm: Double = v2.norm(2.0)

    1 - (dotProduct / (v1norm * v2norm))
  }

  override def getName: String = "cosine"

  override def getDescription: String = "Cosine distance"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [norm](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet#linear-algebra-functions), seems there is no `implicits` for `Vector`, you should use it like:

```
  import breeze.linalg._
  val v1norm: Double = norm(v1, 2.0)
```

Comment: So I had used it wrongfully and this worked fine. Thank You !